# Pass input file through pipe as argument?

Tags: shell, find, pipe, xargs

I have two issues. I am  trying to pass files through a pipe as an argument, and I am trying to use that file as a variable inside the `sh` function.

Here is my command:

```
find . -name 'segment*' | xargs -n1 -P4 sh someFunction.sh
```

Here, my line is finding all files that look like "`segment.something`" and passing it into the right side of the pipe. 
In `someFunction.sh`, I need the name of the file as an argument. Let's say the file being inputted in `segment1`.

The `someFunction.sh` will print out every line of `segment1` (for instance).

How do I pass output from the left hand side of the pipe to the right hand side, and then how do I call it within `someFunction.sh`?

Answer (score 4):

Your command

```
$ find . -name 'segment*' | xargs -n1 -P4 sh someFunction.sh
```

has the effect that at most four copies of the `someFunction.sh` shell script will be started (`-P 4`) in parallel (new ones will be spawed as soon as the old ones are done), each one getting one filename as its argument (`-n 1`).

This means that each invocation of your script will look like

```
sh someFunction.sh segmentsomething
```

Inside the script, the shell will put the values of the *positional parameters* (the arguments on the command line) into `$1`, `$2` etc. (`$0` usually contains the name of the script itself).  In your case, `$1` will contain the name of the file, and the others will be empty.

So, in the script:

```
filename="$1"

echo "$filename"
cat "$filename"
```

That's that.  Now, usually when one uses `find` to look for files and pass their filenames to `xargs` there is the issue with wonky filenames that people tend to remind each other of, and I'll do that here too.

The `find` utility passes filenames separated by whitespace.  That's no good if you have filenames with spaces in them as that would cause problems for `xargs` to invoke your script with proper names.

Therefore, it's good practice to *always* use `-print0` with `find` and `-0` with `xargs`, which means that the filenames, instead of being space-separated, are separated by `nul` characters (`\0`).  This makes it a lot safer.

Thus:

```
$ find . -name 'segment*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P4 sh someFunction.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this assuming `someFunction.sh` is in your working directory.

```
find . -name 'segment*' -print0| xargs -0 -n1 -P4 ./someFunction.sh
```

The `-print0` and `-0` allow for files with spaces in the name (A common problem).
    In my `someFunction.sh` I have

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Arg: " $1  
cat $1
```

Which simply echo's out the file name then writes the contents of the file passed to `someFunction.sh`

Comment: `-print0` is missing in example.